# zipline: How to find the sid of symbol such as "AAPL"

Tags: assets, zipline

I want to use the data in the zipline to do some research. (not in the backtesting )
So how can I find the sid from symbol in a just "helloworld.py"?

zipline.assets.asset, it seems that the asset is implmented in c language.

Thanks
Arthur